# Searching for a particular word in a file in C

Tags: c, string

Good day y'all i have been trying to find if a particular remark or word exist in a file. Don't know why the else part isn't working. How do I do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *file = "mar";
    char *str1 = "PASS";
    char *str2 = "FAIL";
    char *find,*f;
    char line[20] ;

    fp = fopen(file, "r");

    while( fgets (line, 20, fp)!=NULL )
    {
       if((find = strstr(line,str1)) || (find = strstr(line,str2)))
          {
              printf("ok");
              break;
          }
        else//if(find != strstr(line,str1))// || (find != strstr(line,str2)))
          {
              printf("Still processing");
              break;
          }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You have commented some part in `else` . Please elaborate on not working and what do you expect .

Comment: The `break` in the `else` clause probably isn't required.  It will cause the loop to end the first time it doesn't find the word.  I.e. it will only ever call `fgets` once.

Comment: drop `else` and what comes after

Comment: Debugger................DCV

Comment: okay. I wanted it to open the file if any of the words are present or print out "script not yet scored". if the words don't match it prints nothing and exit. Thanks

Comment: You're getting the file contents 20 chars at a time, what would happen if the strings you're looking for start at offset 19, 39, 59 etc... You could end up searching for `PASS` in _"this is a string, PA"_, and _"SS. but it doesn't. "_

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any condition in the `else` part. You also don't need to store the pointer returned by `strstr` since you don't use it.

The problem is probably because of the `break` statement you have in the `else` part. Consider what would happen if anyone of lines do *not* have 
either of those words you look for: It would go into the `else` part and break the loop. Hence, it will not read the file anymore.

Your if-else can be simplified to:

```
   if( strstr(line,str1) || strstr(line,str2) )
      {
          printf("ok");
          break; // If you want to continue searching the file after 
                 // first match, then you should remove this `break;`
      }
    else
      {
          printf("Still processing");
      }
```

I would avoid hard-coding array size in [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html). Instead the loop condition can be written as:

```
   while( fgets (line, sizeof line, fp) ) {
      ...
   }
```

Comment: An eror in program flow that would have been revealed immediately by the most trivial attempt at debugging:(

Comment: @I3x. I have tried that but still not working. Just going straight to the else part even when the words exist in the file.

Comment: @ConnelBLAZE Check if `fopen` succeeded: `if(!fp) { perror("fopen"); exit(1); }`. Do you have lines longer than 20 in the file? Do you have matching words at all? Do you have the permission to read the file? Check all these too.

Comment: @I3x. Yes it did. Just don't know what to do. Will be submitting ma project soon and this is the only thing keeping me. Just don't want the student to see his/her results till after the faculty has put in remarks either "PASS"/"FAIL".

Comment: @ConnelBLAZE Well, change the permission of the file then. You should add that condition (in my prev comment) to your code and probably increase the line size to 256 or something like that (it still wouldn't handle the lines longer than that. But 20 is too small).